# Can a "select a missing 3rd symbol" puzzle made at least a bit difficult?

Tags: pattern, visual, puzzle-creation, symbols, progressive-matrix

Looking at all the Mensa IQ test puzzles, usually there are two rows with in total 6-8 symbols and where you need to choose the last one properly to match the pattern.

I wonder whether at least a bit difficult puzzle of the same principle could be made just with 3 or 4 symbols, meaning you actually see just 2 or 3 of them, respectively, and need to fill in the last one.

If so, what would be an example of a logic or pattern for these?

Comment: I believe you might mean _**M**ensa_ IQ test puzzles, and talking about what puzzles these in particular are called, I think they are called *progressive matrices* (or *Raven matrices*, I don't know). I'd have to do some more research on this, so for now, this comment is just what I think. **Edit:** See [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/54341/ravens-style-iq-question).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are three puzzles with $3$ visual images, each being $2\times 2$ Raven matrices:

- > [image: First image] 
  >  
  >  [here](http://sashazd.herokuapp.com/projects/2014/09/30/solving-ravens-progressive-matrices/)
- > [image: Second image] 
  >  
  >  [here](http://www.tedaltenberg.com/cabrillo/cis132/final/ravens.php)

This last one is a little more unique, but quite easy like the previous ones:

- > [image: Thir dimage] 
  >  
  >  [here](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/questions/19598/raven-progressive-matrix-whys-my-chosen-square-wrong)

I cannot find such a puzzle with just $2$ visual designs. I guess it is unlikely because the more objects there are in the puzzle, the more specific the pattern. Like, I might have the sequence $2$, $3$. You might think the next number is $4$. But the answer is actually $5$ (the sequence is just prime numbers, and not numbers ascending by $1$, though how were you supposed to know that from just two terms?).

Hence why the puzzles shown in this answer have a clear and obvious pattern, and thus very trivial and not challenging.

That's just my two cents.